# R - grepl conditions on vector to exclude exact match

Tags: regex, r, grepl

I am struggling to properly exclude variables when I use `grepl`.

Imagine my vector is

```
 vec = c("POP MUSIC",  "TOP THE POPS", "POPEYE", "MARY POPPINS")
```

I want to `grepl` `POP` when I visually recognise pop music. 
In my example I want then to exclude `"POPEYE", "MARY POPPINS"`.

How could I do something like ? 
And why this line of code does not work ?

```
vec[ grepl("POP", vec ) & grepl("^POPEY$", vec ) & grepl("^MARY POPPINS$", vec ) ]
```

**desired results**

`"POP MUSIC" "TOP THE POPS"`

thanks

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: Do you just want to get all values with `POP` as a whole word? [`grep("\\bPOP\\b", vec, value = TRUE)`](http://ideone.com/bPexuP)?

Comment: I think this is a dupe, but `nah = vec[3:4]; setdiff( grep("POP", vec), grep(paste0(nah, collapse="|"), vec))`.

Comment: Or `setdiff( vec[grep("POP", vec)], nah )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `grep` solution:

```
vec = c("POP MUSIC",  "TOP THE POPS", "POPEYE", "MARY POPPINS") 
grep("(?i)\\bPOPS?\\b", vec, value = TRUE)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/A28Ucm)

The regex `(?i)\\bPOPS?\\b` matches a whole word `POP` or `POPS` in a case-insensitive way (due to `(?i)`) and if found, the value is returned (due to `value=TRUE`).

You may need to adjust the regex as per your needs (e.g. `(?i)\\bPOP(S|PING)?\\b` to also allow `popping`).